# How Javascript geolocation show location after position fixed?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps

is there any way to check if postition fixed , and then display it in my input text. this my code

```
function get_mylocation() {
  var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 0
  }
  watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);


  function onSuccess(position) {
    var mylocation = position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
    $$("#mylocation").val(mylocation);      


  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
  }
}


get_mylocation() /*run*/
```

but this code show my location before location fixed, how to fix it ?

Comment: check if you've moved in `onSuccess` function

Comment: how to check  ? @JaromandaX

Comment: check if the latitude or longitude has changed

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by fix?
 - fixed in the sense when the user has stopped moving or 
 - fixed in the sense the gps is not returning accurate result?

Incase of former check if the location has not changed by certain distance between the previous call and current.

Incase of latter you can
You can have a timeout for few seconds for the gps to settle.

`watchPosition() - Returns the current position of the user and continues to return updated position as the user moves.`

You can also use the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();` to get the fixed current position.

Comment: i mean "Gps Locked" on notification. so when gps locked, call function clearWatch

Comment: Did you try to add timeout?
Something like this?
``navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, handleLocationError, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 10000});``